# Why is scroll processed via handler while resize is processed via overriden method in ScrollPanel?

Tags: events, gwt, resize, scroll

Why is GWT designed in such a way? What is the principal difference between resize and scroll events?

Answer (score 4):

Because there's no event for resizing in browsers (there's resizing at the window-level, but not element-level), contrary to scroll events.

Thus, resizing "notification" is "emulated" in GWT: if you use a `RootLayoutPanel` or `ResizeLayoutPanel`, it'll listen for window resize events and propagates them downwards to its `RequiresResize`children (which will propagate downwards too, if they are `ProvidesResize` widgets themselves).
Explicitly setting the size of a `ProvidesResize` widget will also notify its `RequiresResize` children; as well as resizing areas of a layout panel (programmatically for `DockLayoutPanel` and `LayoutPanel` –among others–, and/or done by the user for a `SplitLayoutPanel` or `StackLayoutPanel`).

You'll note that `ScrollPanel` is both a `RequiresResize` (will be notified by its parent `ProvidesResize` widget that its size might have changed) and `ProvidesResize` (will notify its child widget if its a `RequiresResize`).