# gwt scroll pane that takes it size from the other components

Tags: java, gwt, layout, scrollbar

I have a screen in gwt where a portion of the screen has a scroll panel. There is a header bar at the top and the rest of the screen is in a scroll panel.

Problem is I can only get the scroll bars to appear if I set the absolute height of the scroll panel. The content in the scroll panel is bigger than the scroll panel but the scroll bars don't appear unless I specify the size of the scroll panel absolutely. The problem with this is it does not take into account the size of the browser window...

Comment: I think that's already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389599/why-is-scroll-processed-via-handler-while-resize-is-processed-via-overriden-meth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this answer helped me [gwt-layoutpanel-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740617/gwt-layoutpanel-size).

Basically, the bottom line is that if you want the scroll panel to resize and maintain the scroll bars all your parent containers must implement RequiresResize so that the scroll panel can listen for the event and act accordingly.

Your flexibility is severely limited when requiring this behaviour as you can only put the scroll panel inside elements that implement RequiresResize/Provides Resize which are the *LayoutPanels...